# Export out keyframe within object range

Tags: python, animation, export, maya

Is it possible to solely out export the keyframes of a given object within its own keyframed ranged?

Example, `camA` is keyframed in the range of Frame 1 to 10. But when I tried to export out this camera in another format, it is taking into account of the overall time slider instead. And hence `exported_camA` is keyframed in the range of Frame 1 to 24 (24 is the max range of my time slider)

Will this be possible? I tried out using `cmds.playbackOptions` but apparently it is also exporting out according to the time slider range

```
def __init__(self, transform, startAnimation, endAnimation, cameraObj):

    self.fileExport = []
    print ">>> Exported : %s" %self.fileExport

    mayaGlobal = OpenMaya.MGlobal()
    mayaGlobal.viewFrame(OpenMaya.MTime(1))

    for i in range(startAnimation, endAnimation):

        focalLength = cameraObj.focalLength()

        vFilmApp = cameraObj.verticalFilmAperture()

        focalOut = 2* math.degrees(math.atan(vFilmApp * 25.4/ (2* focalLength)))

        myEuler = OpenMaya.MEulerRotation()
        spc = OpenMaya.MSpace.kWorld

        trans = transform.getTranslation(spc)

        rotation = transform.getRotation(myEuler)
        rotVector = OpenMaya.MVector(myEuler.asVector())

        self.fileExport.append((str(i) + '\t' + str(trans[0]) + "\t" + str(trans[1]) + "\t" + str(trans[2]) + "\t" + str(math.degrees(rotVector[0])) + "\t" + str(math.degrees(rotVector[1])) + "\t" + str(math.degrees(rotVector[2])) + "\t" + str(focalOut) + "\n"))

        mayaGlobal.viewFrame(OpenMaya.MTime(i+1))
```

Answer (score 0):

in `cmds` you can get the maximum and minimum times for a given animation like this:

```
key_times = cmds.keyframe('pCube1', attribute = 'translate',  q=True, tc=True)
first_key = key_times[0]
 last_key = key_times[-1]
```

Note that this has to be applied to a particular attribute (in this case, I used 'translate'), otherwise you will get the keys from the first anim curve Maya finds on the object.

That said, it's usually considered best to export either the scene keyframe range or an explicitly set frame range. Otherwise you may have somebody working in a scene and scrubbing the time, then exporting and seeing fewer frames.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I was also condemning if I should allows the freedom of control for users to export the animation via the scene range or just the range as depicted in the said selection. Even so for now, the latter is what I am trying to achieve in my current code. I will take the former into account should I want to further improvise my code. Thanks again!

Comment: How is this answer even correct?  tc is a time argument, not boolean.

Answer (score 0):

I have also found this command - `cmds.findKeyframe` so as to capture the keyframes of the selected object animation and it also aids in my code as well

Though I am not sure if this will generates any adverse effects later on, seeing that I have yet to encounter one :x

For example:

```
minTime = cmds.findKeyframe(which='first') # First keyframe
maxTime = cmds.findKeyframe(which='last')  # Last keyframe
```